# Unhide comment on my post will not work

Tags: facebook-comments

I have made posts where some of my friend's comments are hidden, and I don't know why they've been hidden. When I go to my post and "Unhide" the hidden comment, the action does not stick. When I go back to the post again, the comment has been hidden again. I have closed/reopened my browser, and the comments are still hidden, even though I have gone in and clicked "Unhide." How can I permanently Unhide these comments from my posts??